# How to Tag / Label / Filter DataDog logs

Tags: logging, logstash, logstash-grok, datadog

I’m trying to group logs from a source so I can filter them in or out in DataDog logs.

There is already a grok parser that formats the messages, but how can I add a tag to them?

DataDog seem to use a subset of LogStash grok parsing rules: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/processors/

Eg from Heroku:

```
source=worker.1 dyno=heroku.152688202.1b2da7cb-291c-43ea-b5ee-bf9388bc5c6a 
sample#load_avg_1m=0.06 sample#load_avg_5m=0.14 sample#load_avg_15m=0.09
```

as

```
{ source { worker: 1 }...
```

What I'd like is to add something like a `type`, so I know they are not from the app, eg

```
{ type: 'metrics', source { worker: 1 }...
```

Then I guess I could add the same thing to app logs and add `type: 'app'` to them.

Comment: You can add tags with the common option [add_tag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-add_tag)

Comment: @baudsp thanks for that info, my question wasn't clear but it is relating to DataDog logging, I've updated it a bit now to try and convey that better.

Comment: I think category processor is what I need, just testing it out and will post answer if so https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/processors/?tab=ui#category-processor

Answer (score 0):

Need to use category-processor https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/processing/processors/?tab=ui#category-processor

Example:
[image]

I didn't do enough research before posting this question, but the answer for anyone else looking.